# How to make image responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on codeigniter,i try more but not able to make my image responsive.please help me to find out the solution

here is my Header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/owl.carousel.css'); ?>">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style_new.css'); ?>">
```

I am using bootstrap framework to making my image responsive

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="banner-bg">
  <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-1.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-2.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-3.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
  <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-4.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

I am also using  img-responsive class to make it responsive but its not working.
Then I try to use css to make it responsive .
Here is css.

```
.banner-bg .banner-bg-item img .img-responsive{
max-width: 100%; 
display:block; 
height: auto;
}
```

After try css I didn't get the responsive image.

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: There is a space too much, it should be `.banner-bg .banner-bg-item img.img-responsive`.

Comment: you dont need to add any additional code to make the image responsive if you already have img-responsive class added..

Comment: dhaval chheda ..but class .img-responsive is not working..by adding img-responsive ..its not make image responsive

Comment: Is it possible to provide live url...

Comment: I am working on my local host ..so how can i provide live url ???

Comment: @xr33dx: Create a jsfiddle and reproduce it there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fzqz1o8s/2/

Comment: patrick ..above link there is my code

Comment: @xr33dx: Are you joking? You haven't added the class to the img-tags, you haven't provided example images, you have php code (which won't work), and you haven't loaded the bootstrap css in external resources. Of course *that* won't work. Please provide a *working* example, **with the problems you are facing**, how else are we supposed to help you?

Comment: This question is lacking in quality. You haven't provided a working example, you haven't defined what *you* are referring to as responsive and what part of the responsiveness isn't working. Is you css applied to the images? Are they not resizing properly or not at all? What is the actual behavior, and what behavior are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You have space between img tag or class .img-responsive, so please remove it.

you can write like below:

```
.banner-bg .banner-bg-item img.img-responsive{
 }
```

I think you put the width:100% for image in responsive:

```
.banner-bg .banner-bg-item img.img-responsive{
max-width: 100%; 
display:block; 
height: auto;
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the column class as well like

```
<img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-2.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" alt="">
```

or also alternatively you can add the column class at first like,

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="banner-bg">
         <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-1.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
        <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-2.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
        <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-3.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
        <div class="banner-bg-item"><img  src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/slider-4.jpg'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There might be any inherited properties interfering with the img-responsive class, you can redefine it like 

`.banner-bg .banner-bg-item img .img-responsive {
    all: initial!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}`

if it also did not worked then next step would be to use javascript
`$('.banner-bg .banner-bg-item img .img-responsive').css({
    'all': 'initial',
    'width': '100%',
    'height': 'auto'
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `!important` css property to apply `css` forcefully. hope it works for you.

```
 .banner-bg .banner-bg-item img{
    max-width: 100% !important; 
    }
```

to apply this by `JQuery` add this code to footer and make sure jquery library is connected.

```
<script>
(function($) {  
$(".banner-bg .banner-bg-item img").css("width","100%", 'important');
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

JQUERY STYLE PROPERTY

```
jQuery.style(name, value, priority);
```

Comment: can you apply this by JavaScript??
because it is possible to have this error by slider's js code.

Comment: How can i apply ..please suggest..gautam

Comment: wait i will be back shortly

Comment: Gautam jha ...where i put  the jquery style property

Comment: if you are using any master js file then put this code in that file without HTML `<script>` tag otherwise add this code after end of  your silder's file attachments with  `<script>` tag .

Comment: I add this code before </body> tag..and also add <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'); ?>"></script> this in footer ...but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110802/discussion-between-xr33dx-and-gautam-jha).